# Processing "update elements" & "get min value among all element" queries efficiently

Tags: algorithm, performance, minimum

### Question

You are given an array `a = [a0, a1, ..., an-1]`, process these `Q` queries. The queries has following two types:

- Given two integers `i` and `x`, update `ai` to `x`
- Find the minimum value among all elements in array

I already know the algorithm with segment tree (range minimum query), and the time complexity is `O(n log n)`. But this way also can calculate the minimum value among any section, so I think there is more simple and good performance way that can process these two types of queries.

Is there any other way to solve?

Comment: do you want an online algorithm or offline can do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an array and a minimum heap with references to the heap in the array.

The array has the elements by index (it's basically the actual array you have) and the heap is ordered by value so that the minimum is always on top. You add a reference (a pointer) from each array element to its corresponding node in the heap so you can find it easily there.

To perform the first query you access the array at index `i` and set the element value to `x` (after index validation and all that). Then you update the node in the heap that `ai` points to and heapify. This costs O(log n).

To perform the second query just get the minimum from the heap. O(1).